# submit a form in an iframe from ios device

Tags: ios, forms, iframe, cross-domain, submit

I have an iframe loading in my site from another domain and it contains a form which submits perfectly from desktop browsers and android, but fails on Safari ios. Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get this to submit from ios?